# Could not load file or assembly 'DevComponents.DotNetBar2 Erorr

Tags: c#, .net

Please see this pic

http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-07/95474529960213811860.gif
[image: error]

I have an error and I think it is about Dev Component but I have added Dev component .dll file in my Project!!

The error is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'DevComponents.DotNetBar2,
>   Version=8.1.0.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5fd520d36328f741' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

Help me to solve this problem Please!!

Comment: It can find it just fine, it however found the wrong version.  Not 8.1.0.6.  It is of course unclear how this got messed up on your machine, "added Dev component .dll file" was probably a bad move.  Contact the component vendor for support.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try and remove and re-add the assembly
2. Check if the assembly is in the GAC
3. Check if version is correct. If it is a wrong version the use .config file and redirect version under runtime...dependentAssembly xml tag

Dennis

Comment: I have tried and re added the dll files of Dev component but it still doesn't work!!! :((